# In Corda, how can I execute a flow periodically / at a fixed interval on the node?

Tags: corda

I want my Corda node to run a flow at a fixed interval, e.g. every second. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a service. A service is a long-lived object inside your node. In our service, we'll define a `kickOff` method that runs a separate thread to start our `PeriodicFlow` every second:

```
@CordaService
class PeriodicService(val services: AppServiceHub): SingletonSerializeAsToken() {
    fun kickOff() {
        Thread {
            while (true) {
                services.startFlow(PeriodicFlow())
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            }
        }.start()
    }
}
```

Here is the flow that calls the `kickOff` method. Note the use of `ServiceHub.cordaService` to retrieve the service object.

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class KickOff : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        serviceHub.cordaService(PeriodicService::class.java).kickOff()
    }
}
```

And here is the simple flow that your node runs. Note the `@StartableByService` annotation that allows a service to run the flow.

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByService
class PeriodicFlow : FlowLogic<String>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): String {
        return "Flow called."
    }
}
```